# Efficient way of row binding time series in a data.table, with correctly sorted timestamps

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a more efficient way to row bind (or an efficient merge) two or more massive time series with data table?  The time series have some different columns, so I use `fill = TRUE`.

I want all the rows in each time series to appear in the final data.table.  I can do it below, but the time series stamps are not ordered in `dt3` below.  I have to create `dt4` to get the ordered stamps.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing a kind of rbind/time series merge in data.table?

```
library(data.table)

tm <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-05-12 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-05-14"), by = "hours")
dt <- data.table(time = tm, x = seq(1, length(tm), by = 1))

set.seed(1)

dt2 <- data.table(time = tm[sample(length(tm), size = 8)] + rnorm(n = 8, 0, 60),
                 y = rnorm(8))

# Can a one liner here get me the output in `dt4` with some kind of row bind? 
#  Is there a way to do a row bind here instead that avoids the creation of a new object dt4 that takes the sorted rows?

dt3 <- rbind(dt, dt2, fill = TRUE)

dt4 <- dt3[order(time)]

                      tail(dt4, 20)
#                   time  x           y
# 1: 2018-05-13 08:00:00 33          NA
# 2: 2018-05-13 09:00:00 34          NA
# 3: 2018-05-13 10:00:00 35          NA
# 4: 2018-05-13 11:00:00 36          NA
# 5: 2018-05-13 12:00:00 37          NA
# 6: 2018-05-13 13:00:00 38          NA
# 7: 2018-05-13 14:00:00 39          NA
# 8: 2018-05-13 14:59:41 NA  0.94383621
# 9: 2018-05-13 15:00:00 40          NA
# 10: 2018-05-13 16:00:00 41          NA
# 11: 2018-05-13 16:01:30 NA  0.82122120
# 12: 2018-05-13 17:00:00 42          NA
# 13: 2018-05-13 17:00:44 NA -0.04493361
# 14: 2018-05-13 18:00:00 43          NA
# 15: 2018-05-13 19:00:00 44          NA
# 16: 2018-05-13 20:00:00 45          NA
# 17: 2018-05-13 21:00:00 46          NA
# 18: 2018-05-13 22:00:00 47          NA
# 19: 2018-05-13 23:00:00 48          NA
# 20: 2018-05-14 00:00:00 49          NA
```

Comment: may i know why must it be a 1-liner? maybe `rbindlist(list(dt,dt2), fill=TRUE)[order(time)]`? and in R lingo, the word merge is more like sql-join (left and right table, not top and bottom). see `?merge`

Comment: The time series are really big.  10+ million rows in each series.  wondering if there is a better way to do it than what I propose, as i do this operaiton many times in a loop. My concern was that perhaps `dt3[order(time)]` was an expensive operation after already doing the rbind?  in `xts` id just do a `merge` and it would handle the ordering in the merge automatically

Comment: what im looking for is like an outer merge in a sense

Comment: thanks dww.  why dont you put that as an answer. i thought i was overcomplicating it with doing the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the time columns set as keys

```
setkey(dt, time)
setkey(dt2, time)
```

Then you can use `merge.data.table`

```
merge(dt,dt2,all=TRUE)
```

Note, if the time series are already known to be sorted (which dt is, but dt2 is not), you can speed up a bit more by just setting the 'sorted' attribute of the data.tables, rather than calling `setkey`.

```
attr(dt, 'sorted') = 'time'
```

Comment: Thanks for the attribute sorted tip. where can I read about "tricks" like that for data.table?  Specifically for time series problems

Comment: hmmm - I'm not sure I've seen the attr trick documented anywhere. In general, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html is a good resource